# Synchronization between SharePoint 2007 and Outlook 2007 is not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization, outlook

I have a problem with the SharePoint and Outlook calendar synchronization. When I drag and drop an appointment or meeting from outlook calendar into SharePoint calendar, I can see that it is appeared on SharePoint calendar. Till this, I am good.

But, when I update the calendar item in outlook and sync both the calendars again, I don't see the updated on SharePoint calendar. Same issue with vice versa.

Can any one please help me if you had run into this sort of scenario.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [sharepoint.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. When you drag an item from a SharePoint calendar to an Outlook calendar, this is a very simple copy. There is no link between the two items. If you change the Outlook appointment, it will not update SharePoint. In other words, the two appointments act independently of each other.

We have been working on an Outlook add-in to solve this issue. The add-in called, ProperSync, allows direct syncing between Outlook calendars and SharePoint. You can find more information at www.propersync.com

#### Edit:

As a new feature in ProperSync 1.3 (beta now available) users can connect their Outlook calendar directly with a SharePoint calendar. This links the appointments directly. There is no need to drag and drop, just setup the connection and the appointment in Outlook is the same in SharePoint.

Here is a simple video demo - http://youtu.be/6l6mEsqrutU

*Disclaimer - I am part of the ProperSync team, but hope this is a relevant and helpful posting

Comment: Thanks for your response, Carsten. I have already used the trail version of the ProperSync to display some of the sharepoint custom fields in outlook. 
But what I don't understand is that, what is the benefit of the synchronization then?
Once we synchronize the calendar items and if they are not liked together, we need to do the updates on the both the sides, which is a double work. Please let me know when can we expect the add-in to solve the issue.
Thank you!!